# Calculate total number of characters in all substrings of a string without loops or recursion

Tags: string

A string like `ADAM` has the following substrings

```
A
AD
ADA
ADAM
D
DA
DAM
A
AM
M
```

To calculate the total number of substrings I can do a O(1) operation as follows `ADAM -> 10`.

```
function calcNumSubstrings(strlen) {
  return (strlen * (strlen + 1) / 2);
}
```

What I need is the sum of all characters in all of those substrings. In the case of `ADAM` this is `20`. To get this I can do an O(N) operation like this:

```
function calcTotalLettersInAllSubstrings(strlen) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= strlen; i++) {
    total += calcNumSubstrings(i);
  }
  return total;
}
```

This is basically: `((1*(1+1))/2) + ((2*(2+1))/2) + ((3*(3+1))/2) + ((4*(4+1))/2)`

Is there an O(1) way of calculating this or am I breaking my head over nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do some math. Let n be length of string and let sum(expr) be the sum from r=1 to r=n of the given expression, then for a given substring length r you have (n+1-r) possible substrings, hence :

```
sum(r(n+1-r)) = (n+1)sum(r) - sum(r^2)
```

Now refer to standard sums of series [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/), which gives :

```
sum(r) = n(n+1)/2 

sum(r^2) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

Therefore :

```
sum(r(n+1-r)) = n(n+1)^2 / 2 - n(n+1)(2n+1)
```

checking for n=4

```
sum(r(5-r)) = 50 - 30 = 20
```

Simplifying this expression gives :

```
sum(r(n+1-r)) = n(n+1)/2( (n+1) - (2n+1)/3)
              = n(n+1)/6( 3n+3 -2n -1)
              = n(n+1)(n+2)/6
```

As above

Answer (score 2):

The general case is : `n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6`

Where `n` is the number of characters in the string.

So in this case, the number of characters is 4: `4*(4+1)*(4+2)/6 = 20`

Comment: @WaldoBronchart, don't forget to mark as answered! :) Being perfectly honest, I know enough algebra to see that the divide by 2s within each block can be simplified into a single division on the outer block - after that, I just quickly looked up how a sequence of those terms is summed!

Comment: Accepted @the4thamigo_uk's answer because it refers to the general problem of "Sums of Series". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WaldoBronchart, no problem. And I think the4thamigo_uk earned it! :)